# Meanings of "a few hours from Wake Forest" and "Sophia might as well have said she'd been raised on Mars"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, literature

I found this sentence in *The Longest Ride*

> Marcia was from Charlotte, born and raised only **a few hours from Wake Forest**. Sophia could still remember Marcia's bewildered reaction when she said she had grown up in Jersey City. For all intent and purpose, **Sophia might as well have said she'd been raised on Mars**.

I have few questions regarding this sentence -

1. What is the meaning of "a few hours from West Forest"?
2. It's not very clear why "Sophia might as well have said she'd been raised on Mars"?

Answer (score 3):

*A few hours journey from Wake Forest* means that the journey between Charlotte and ‘Wake Forest’ takes only a few hours.

Charlotte and Wake Forest are in the same state, only about 150 miles apart—say, two and a half hours by car. Jersey City is more than 600 miles from Charlotte, and three states away. There is, moreover, a great cultural divide: North Carolina is of the South and was until very recently a predominantly rural state, while Jersey City is a part of the monster northeast conurbation around New York City. For Marcia, Jersey City is unimaginably remote—as remote, to her mind, as Mars.

Comment: Yes it is Wake Forest. Now I got the whole thing. Thank you very much.